# LINQ XML obtaining child nodes of parent node

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Please find xml data below. I would like to obtain nodes with keys "Sub1" and "Sub2" using LINQ query, given that I know that the parent node has url="#", title="item 1", and key="Item1".

```
<root>
<node title="Partner" url="" description="99" roles="GuidIdHere"></node>
<node title="Test" url="" description="51" roles="8b0c0c4f" key="sample">
    <node url="#" title="item 1" description="" key="Item1">
        <node url="#" title="Sub 1" description="" key="Sub1" />
        <node url="#" title="Sub 2" description="" key="Sub2" />
    </node>
    <node url="#" title="item 2" description="" key="Item2" />
    <node url="#" title="item 3" description="" key="Item3" />
</node>
</root>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var result = from x in doc.Root.Descendents("node")
             where (string)x.Attribute("url") == "#"
                && (string)x.Attribute("title") == "item 1"
                && (string)x.Attribute("key") == "Item1"
             from y in x.Elements("node")
             where (string)x.Attribute("key") == "Sub1"
                || (string)x.Attribute("key") == "Sub2"
             select y;
```

Comment: I just had to change doc.Root.Descendants to doc.Descendants, but otherwise this was perfect! Thanks!